# How do you perform a test assertion for two views with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have been trying to follow the documentation [here](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html).
I want to be able to check the text of two views for some text content. I think I know how to do if for one view but I am unsure how to do it for two or more.

```
onView(withid(R.id.tvUsername)).check(matches(withText("User1")));
```

This will check that a view has the specified text but what should i do when i want to check that this view and another have some text. I need them both to pass for the test to pass.